# Combining Multiple If Statements for Growth Rate Calculation

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

Even though I'd describe myself as an advanced Excel user, I've experienced some problems solving the following task in Excel.

I'm working on a table more or less identical to the table shown in the screenshot. The task is to calculate the growth rate for some values, e.g. earnings. However, there are some conditions that should be fulfilled while calculating the growth rate.

Below you'll find a table with the conditions I'm looking for.

I would be very grateful for any hint or solution to this problem...

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

[image]

Comment: Creating a separate if statement for each condition is not a big deal... but I've already spent two or three hours trying to combine these single if statement.

Comment: Show your formulas. Usually it's just a matter of figuring out the priority for testing, and ordering the formulas in that order.  On the Excel worksheet, the `IF` will stop when `logical_test=TRUE`.

Answer (score 0):

I could get somewhat close to the requirement but not exactly (See the last row in the image below).

The order of logical test matters here + you have to modify the second condition to include the possibility that the numerator is not zero.

Here is the statement. I have tested it in libre-office but should work in excel too.

```
=IF(A1=A2,IFS(OR(ISBLANK(C1),ISBLANK(C2)),"NULL",AND(C2<=0,C1<>0),"NULL",AND(C2=0,C1=0),"0.00%",AND(C2>0,C1<=0),"-100%",AND(C1>0,C2>0),(C1-C2)/C2*100),"First Year")
```

The output is as below.

[image]

**Edit after nice suggestion by @RonRosenfeld**

New formula.

```
IF(A1=A2,IFS(OR(ISBLANK(C1),ISBLANK(C2)),"NULL",AND(C2<=0,C1<>0),"NULL",AND(C2=0,C1=0),"0.00%",AND(C2>0,C1<=0),"-100%",AND(C1>0,C2>0),(C1-C2)/C2*100),IF(ISBLANK(A2),"","First Year"))
```

Updated table looks like below

[image]

**Edit after OP added a new sub-problem.**

Suspecting the cause is whitespaces in cells which, otherwise, look blank. If such is the case, then below "may" work.

```
=IF(A1=A2,IFS(OR(C1=REPT(" ",LEN(C1)),C2=REPT(" ",LEN(C2)),ISBLANK(C1),ISBLANK(C2)),"NULL",AND(C2<=0,C1<>0),"NULL",AND(C2=0,C1=0),"0.00%",AND(C2>0,C1<=0),"-100%",AND(C1>0,C2>0),(C1-C2)/C2*100),IF(ISBLANK(A2),"","First Year"))
```

Comment: You could correct the last row by using an initial condition `if(isblank(a2),"", ...`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thank you. Editing the answer

Comment: Thank you very very much, both of you! I very appreciate your help.
As far as I can see, your solutions works perfectly well.

Comment: One issue remains: I got the table with all the data from a colleague who copied it from a database. If I apply your formula, I get an error message every time it refers to one of the empty cells. These cells are actually empty but I can only solve this problem when I click on the empty cell and press the "delete" button on my keyboard.
Is there a way with which I can "format" all cells to solve this? My table has thousands of rows and pressing the "delete" button for all empty cells isn't possible.

Comment: @MSC Updating my guesstimate solution

Comment: @Amit What do means with "updating"? I've tried several things, e.g. making a hard copy of the data in a new sheet or copying the data in a new sheet via a simple formula but it didn't work.

Comment: @MSC did you try the recent most formula? I updated it recently. Your original problem said that "numerator or denominator is an empty cell"..so I posted the original answer thinking that it is a blank cell ..However that did not work out for you when you copied your colleagues sheet ....what I think you are dealing with is one or more whitespaces .. it will look empty but it is not ..